# Python multiprocessing the value set in run function not reflected in the object

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am running the below code

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Value
class TestMultiprocess(Process):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.variable={"value":"initial"}
  def run(self):
    print("executing the run function")
    self.variable={"value":"new"}
    

t=TestMultiprocess()
t.start()
t.join()
print(t.variable) #prints {"value":"initial"}, (I expected {"value":"new"})
```

I am setting the value of the variable in the run function but this value is not getting reflected in the object (**It still holds the value initialised in constructor**). Why is this??

How do I set/change am attribute value in the run function of the class inheriting multiprocessing and use the value from the client code which creates the object of the class. I looked at multiprocessing.values but this does not have support for dictionaries. The attribute value I need to set is a dictionary

Comment: You need to use `multiprocessing.Manager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process is running in a different address space. Therefore, your `TestMultiProcess` instance must be serialized and sent to that child process's address space where it is then deserialized (all of this is done with the `pickle` module). So what is being updated is a copy of your instance that is in the child process's address space; the main process's instance is never updated.

The simplest solution is to used a *managed dictionary*. The actual dictionary "lives" in the address space of the `Manager` and variable `managed_dict` in the code below is actually a proxy object such that when one of its methods is called, the method name and its arguments are sent to the `Manager` process where the actual dictionary is updated:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

class TestMultiprocess(Process):
    def __init__(self, managed_dict):
        super().__init__()
        self.managed_dict = managed_dict
        self.managed_dict["value"] = "initial"

    def run(self):
        print("executing the run function")
        self.managed_dict["value"] = "new"


# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        managed_dict = manager.dict()
        t = TestMultiprocess(managed_dict)
        print(t.managed_dict)
        t.start()
        t.join()
        print(t.managed_dict)
```

Prints:

```None
{'value': 'initial'}
executing the run function
{'value': 'new'}
```